# Is there an API or programmatic way to convert ".htaccess" rewrites to "web.config" IIS Rewrites?

Tags: htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I know I can do it in IIS Manager, but I am looking for some programmatic way to do it. We need to do this for customer all the time.  So it would be great if there's a programmatic way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a reliable programmatic way to automatically convert *[.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)* files to *[web.config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config)* files because IIS's configuration is quite different from Apache's, as well as their configuration file formats.

There are [some](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx) sites which claim to do automatic conversions, but the scope and accuracy of these are *questionable*.

You can however suggest that your client add an IIS module that uses standard regular expressions, since Apache's [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) module uses [Perl Compatible Regular Expression](http://pcre.org/) vocabulary - see:  [Apache - mod_rewrite-Regular Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex)

One such module is [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/), which is written in pure C/C++. From their FAQ's:

> ISAPI_Rewrite is a rule-based rewriting tool to rewrite requested URLs
>   on the fly. ISAPI_Rewrite uses regular expression rules. With regular
>   expressions you don't need to write a thousands check strings. The
>   comparison and replace of URLs can be done with a few string patterns.

Using regular expressions for IIS should help to greatly speedup conversions of Apache [RewriteRule's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: How bout sites like cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx and htaccesstowebconfig.com? I wonder how they do it.

Comment: I'd suggest testing the output of these before thinking about _how_ they do it, or using them...